# CDF of max of $n$ cauchy variates

Tags: probability, distributions, extreme-value, order-statistics, cauchy-distribution

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$ are iid copies of a standard cauchy variate with pdf
$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)},0<x< \infty. $$
Define:
$$ Y=1+ \underset{1 \leq i \leq n}\max X_i.$$ I want to find the cdf of $Y.$

**My attempt:-** First we try to find the cdf of $Z=\underset{1 \leq i \leq n}{\max} X_i$ as follows;
if the cdf of $X_i$ is $F_X(x)$, then
$$F_Z(z)= (F_X(x))^n$$ Or,
$$F_Z(z)=  \int_0^z \left(\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)} \right )^n$$
Now I am not sure whether I am right and how to proceed further .For any help I will be  greatly obliged

Comment: When $Y=1+Z$ and you have the distribution of $Z,$ apply the definition $F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(1+Z\le y) = \Pr(Z\le y-1) = F_Z(y-1).$

Comment: whubers approach is commonly referred to as the "CDF-method". Contrast with the Jacobian method, two essential techniques for calculating PDFs and CDFs of changes-of-variable.

Comment: BTW, your expression for $F_Z$ isn't quite correct: the lower bound needs to be $-\infty,$ not $0;$ you need a "$\mathrm dx$" to indicate the variable of integration, and you need to raise the integral to the power $n,$ not the integrand.  The preceding equation makes no sense unless you use a consistent name for the argument, either "$x$" or "$z.$"

Answer (score 11):

You ask about the distribution of the maximum order statistic. There are many similar questions, for other distribution, so follow the outlines of for instance [Distribution of extreme values, case of uniform](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333105/distribution-of-extreme-values-case-of-uniform)  or [Distribution of sample maximum from exponential distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/440984/distribution-of-sample-maximum-from-exponential-distribution).

Doing so, simply differentiate the $n$th power of the Cauchy cumulative distribution function, and you will find
$$
   \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\arctan \left(t \right)}{\pi}\right)^{n} n}{\pi  \left(t^{2}+1\right) \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\arctan \left(t \right)}{\pi}\right)}
$$
You can then take care of adding 1 yourself.

As for the cdf, the above density must be integrated. Using maple, I do not find a very useful expression with a general $n$, but for specific values of $n$, I can get complicated expressions. As an example, for $n=10$ I get
$$
    \frac{\pi^{10}+20 \arctan \! \left(t \right) \pi^{9}+180 \arctan \! \left(t \right)^{2} \pi^{8}+960 \arctan \! \left(t \right)^{3} \pi^{7}+3360 \arctan \! \left(t \right)^{4} \pi^{6}+8064 \arctan \! \left(t \right)^{5} \pi^{5}+13440 \arctan \! \left(t \right)^{6} \pi^{4}+15360 \arctan \! \left(t \right)^{7} \pi^{3}+11520 \arctan \! \left(t \right)^{8} \pi^{2}+5120 \arctan \! \left(t \right)^{9} \pi +1024 \arctan \! \left(t \right)^{10}}{1024 \pi^{10}}
$$
Even for $n=100$ I get an expression, But I doubt it is very useful, as it will fit a complete page in a printed book.

Comment: what is the cdf

Comment: For the expansion. +1.

Comment: If you differentiated to get the pdf, you already had the cdf before you differentiated; you don't need to integrate again.  (leaving the +1 part aside, which is easily dealt with)